# Configure poetry to install private (commercial) package using token

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to install the python package `prodigy` using poetry. The pip method is as follows

```
pip install prodigy -f https://XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX@download.prodi.gy
```

Where `XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` is my private token.

How do I do this using poetry? I've tried added `https://download.prodi.gy` as a `source` i.e.

```
poetry source add prodigy https://download.prodi.gy
```

But I'm not sure how to configure the authentication. I've also tried

```
poetry source add prodigy XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX@https://download.prodi.gy
```

But this fails with

```
401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://download.prodi.gy/download/prodigy-1.12.7-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl
```

Poetry suggests `poetry config http-basic.foo <username> <password>` but I don't think this is basic auth?